# Python- How to find the height of standard binary search tree?

Tags: python, json, binary-search-tree

I've a json file of type `[{"score": 68},{"score": 78}]`

I need to find the height of standard binary search tree that is made using the scores of all the objects. How can I do it?

This is what I'm doing. I'm first getting all the scores and storing inside  the json file and then applying the formula.

```
import ijson 
import math

f = open ('data_large')
content = ijson.items(f, 'item')
n = len(list(i['score'] for i in content))

height = math.ceil(math.log((n+1),2)-1)

print height
```

Well, this does gives me the correct answer, but wanted to know 2 things?

**1)** Whether this formula will also be valid in case when there are duplicates in the list, since I need to develop a BST which can have duplicates as well?

**2)** I think `n = len(list(i['score'] for i in content))` is useless because since I dont need the node values to calculate the height of the BST, but only the length of the list. Is there any way I can calculate the number of entries so that I omit this line and calculate the total nuber of entries in the json file, which will serve the purpose of `n`?

The other thing is I also wanted to calculate is the unique scores as well from the file. So, this is how I'm doing `print set(i['score'] for i in content)` , but it takes `201secs` to execute since the file is so large( `256MB`, hence used `ijson` for **fast** processing ), hence there are multiple entries inside the content. Can I make this statement much more time-efficient. If yes, **How?**

Comment: The way you're trying to calculate the height of the tree only works for a balanced tree. A generic binary tree's height depends on the order of which the nodes are added. In the worst case (already sorted data) it can degenerate to a tree with height n. So if you don't use a balanced tree, then you'd need to construct the binary tree to determine it's height.

Comment: I recommend you move your last paragraph into a new question and edit it out of this one - you're likely to get more focused and helpful answers that way.

Comment: @mata- Since I'm fetching the values(scores) from the json file, hence the order in which the values comes isn't guaranteed. Hence, every compilation will result in a different tree. That's why I'm assuming that the tree constructed will be balanced. Feel free to counter my statement.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes/no. If you've added a property to each node which counts the number of times that node has been inserted into the tree then you still have a BST and the answer is yes.

If you actually want duplicate nodes, then you'd need modify the BST property. The unmodified property says that items smaller than X go left and items greater than X go right. If you instead say items greater than or equal to X to right, then it's easy to see that you can make the tree arbitrarily high by adding many duplicate items and the answer is no.

2) Have you tried `list(content)`? Of course, you cannot build a BST without somehow removing duplicate nodes, this cannot be used to calculate the height of the BST. You need to remove duplicate items. This leads to your third question.

3) As regards the `print set(i['score']...` You shouldn't bundle separate questions together like this as it will lead you down the dark path to having different answers addressing different parts of your question. However, the code you've write certainly does have something Pythonic about it. So you've got to ask yourself if it's really worth *your* time (which is often the only time that really matters) to try to find a more convoluted, but quicker solution.